# Name collision on tag beanstalk

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

In doing some research I noticed that the SO tag [beanstalk](/questions/tagged/beanstalk) is overloaded with several meanings:

- Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, an infrastructure automation tool
- Beanstalkd, a job queue
- Beanstalkapp.com, hosted source control

I'm not sure I have the reputation much less time to fix this, even if I knew what to do.  But I have some ideas.

Each technology should have its own tag.  [beanstalkd](/questions/tagged/beanstalkd) is an actively used tag.  [beanstalkapp](/questions/tagged/beanstalkapp) doesn't seem to be a tag.  The plain [beanstalk](/questions/tagged/beanstalk) tag has an amazon logo -- maybe it should be renamed [aws-beanstalk](/questions/tagged/aws-beanstalk)?

Moreover, I'd say it should not be used as a bare word without being more explicit.  Is it possible to have a negative synonym that prevents its use and forces disambiguation?

Comment: From the tag wiki: *This tag is for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, and should not be confused with beanstalkapp.com which is a git/mercurial hosting app.*

Comment: Agreed that it "should" not be confused.  But it is.  People rarely go to the tag wiki when writing questions.

Comment: Searching for [`[beanstalk] beanstalkapp`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbeanstalk%5D+beanstalkapp) only yields two results...

Answer (score 3):

I think disambiguating is a good idea. Just a couple of suggestions/points:

- The name of the Amazon product is technically [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), and [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Elastic%20Beanstalk%22) refer to it as such. Rather than [aws-beanstalk](/questions/tagged/aws-beanstalk), what about [elastic-beanstalk](/questions/tagged/elastic-beanstalk)? It looks like [the tag is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-beanstalk), to boot, with more questions than [beanstalk](/questions/tagged/beanstalk).
- Specifically to [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146195/name-collision-on-tag-beanstalk#comment418407_146195), people don't tend to refer to Beanstalk (the managed source code service) as Beanstalkapp or Beanstalkapp.com, so trying to search under that term is going to yield less results than it should. Because of this, and this is really bikehshedding, perhaps [beanstalk-app](/questions/tagged/beanstalk-app) is better.

For the purposes of any retag effort and demonstrating there's a name collision involving Beanstalk (the managed source control product), here are the questions tagged [beanstalk](/questions/tagged/beanstalk) that refer to it:

- [Is there any decent git repository manager that's downloadable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222995/is-there-any-decent-git-repository-manager-thats-downloadable)
- [How to deploy Subversion externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907329/how-to-deploy-subversion-externals)
- [Show the latest commit value within a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998869/show-the-latest-commit-value-within-a-web-application)
- [How can I reliably track changes on deployed websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484231/how-can-i-reliably-track-changes-on-deployed-websites)
- [Git Cloning a Sub-Directory in a Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322094/git-cloning-a-sub-directory-in-a-repository)
- [Unable to push on beanstalk master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005878/unable-to-push-on-beanstalk-master)
- [Using Pagelime CMS with Version Control set up (git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336309/using-pagelime-cms-with-version-control-set-up-git)
- [Git, Beanstalk, WordPress Ultimate Deployment Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168129/git-beanstalk-wordpress-ultimate-deployment-approach)
- [Best way to do Beanstalk deployments to a server behind a NAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588470/best-way-to-do-beanstalk-deployments-to-a-server-behind-a-nat)
- [Deploying using Beanstalk SVN Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729136/deploying-using-beanstalk-svn-branches)
- [Git and Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374773/git-and-beanstalk)
- [A way to specify a different host in an SSH tunnel from the host in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985474/a-way-to-specify-a-different-host-in-an-ssh-tunnel-from-the-host-in-use)
- [Which Bug Tracking tools can Beanstalk work with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503727/which-bug-tracking-tools-can-beanstalk-work-with)
- [How to make a branch in SmartGit with beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352142/how-to-make-a-branch-in-smartgit-with-beanstalk)
- [How can I use Subversion, Ubuntu, Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033908/how-can-i-use-subversion-ubuntu-beanstalk)
- [Deployment via Beanstalk - Deploying specific revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304964/deployment-via-beanstalk-deploying-specific-revision)
- [Xcode git Beanstalk authentication required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197563/xcode-git-beanstalk-authentication-required)
- [Beanstalk: How to sync files generated on the server back to the beanstalk repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995961/beanstalk-how-to-sync-files-generated-on-the-server-back-to-the-beanstalk-repos)
- [Making new repository from working copy before committing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576089/making-new-repository-from-working-copy-before-committing-files)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246156/svn-update-in-xcode-not-working
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305472/is-beanstalks-deployment-feature-right-for-me
- [What is the dummy's way to work on wordpress locally (w/versioning) and migrate changes to server, including databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406237/what-is-the-dummys-way-to-work-on-wordpress-locally-w-versioning-and-migrate)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381329/http-403-when-integrating-php-web-hook-to-beanstalk
- [I need help figuring out a good workflow using git and the beantstalk app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355442/i-need-help-figuring-out-a-good-workflow-using-git-and-the-beantstalk-app-servic)
- [Unable to commit to svn with beanstalk on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131965/unable-to-commit-to-svn-with-beanstalk-on-a-mac)
- [Beanstalk like Functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197760/beanstalk-like-functionality)

Generally, it looks like ([git](/questions/tagged/git) | [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) | [version-control](/questions/tagged/version-control)) + [beanstalk](/questions/tagged/beanstalk) gets most of them, but there are a few that don't have a VCS tag.